# aaspectj - installation, ide and in between

Tags: eclipse, aop, aspectj

I'm fairly new to aspectj. and actually need to use it because a feature in spring needs it in order to work.

One thing i don't get. i see that the installation of the aspectj is via eclipse.
so apparently post installation - all my src code and jars are still the same.

so what exactly am i installing? I mean, my project is comprised of jars + .class files so what difference does it make if i install a plugin in my IDE?

p.s I tried to install it but all the installation of aspectj are through maven and I Don't use maven.

Answer (score 0):

there are kind of supporting tools for eclipse that ease aspectJ development (e.g. it shows you weaved pointcuts etc).

AspectJ itself has several options of how to "enrich" your code. You can use [compile-time](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/bytecode-concepts.html) weaving, which modifies your class-files. or you use [load-time weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html), in which case aspectj modifies the bytecode during startup of your application.

either way, after weaving, your code depends on the aspectJ-runtime library, so you need this in your classpath too.

If you use maven, you add aspectj-stuff to it, if you dont, you add it to eclipse itself (which is the plugin for, i guess). just install [ADJT](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) and you are up and running.